# How does the G-WAN pricing/licensing system work?

Tags: licensing, g-wan

I've recently come across a portable HTTP Server called G-WAN that somehow manages to out perform all other HTTP servers in both speed and memory consumption by a factor of four. Now I'm not sure at all how it manages to achieve this, but its approach is that it is planned and developed from the ground up to use the bare-minimum of resources and code to achieve its goal. G-WAN supports various programming languages such as C, C++, Java and PHP.

The software looks very promising, but what I do not understand is its pricing model. You see, G-WAN is freeware, but it has a very elaborate pricing structure that goes into detail on every level all the from hobby-use up to OEM usage. But what confuses me is that the HTTP server is freeware, which means that if you wish to pay for it then pay what you can to the developer.

What exactly does this mean? Does this mean that I can download the software as a I wish, use it on my application and then pay the developer when possible? Does this mean that there is no "free" at all with the software and that I need to pay as soon as it is used in a production environment?

How does its pricing/licensing model work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> You see, G-WAN is freeware, but it has a very elaborate pricing
>   structure that goes into detail on every level all the from hobby-use
>   up to OEM usage

I also was wondering what their business model is, and they told me that they were sharing their work for free (instead of charging for G-WAN) because they intend to sell services based on G-WAN.

So, the software is free for all without conditions or use (non-proffit, education, commercial, etc.). The only restriction made by the license is the acceptation by users to not alter the G-WAN executable (probably to avoid abuses).

The fees that you have seen are for:

- support (Hobbyist, Consultant, Enterprise, 24/24, 365/365): dedicated staff is needed to assist end-users - and this has a cost that someone must pay for;
- custom versions of the software: time is needed to make maintain custom versions - hence the paying options.

All in all, it seems that (a) they are very decided and (b) they know were they are going. And their plans have obviously nothing to do with charging end-users who do not ask for support or custom versions.